# changing value of input box on submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this question In which I have a form having many input boxes. One of the input box has height while its units are cm/inches. Now my API is made in such a way that when the user submits the form the output is given based on the cm unit. Hence if a user selects inches as its unit and clicks submit then I have to convert the value in the height box to cm but not display it on the text box and then send this value to the API call without having to click again on the submit button because user has already done that.

```
<div style="width: 23%; float: left; margin: 0 3% 0 0;">
                <input id="width" type="text" name="width"  required="required" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 23%; float: left; margin: 0 3% 0 0;">
                <input id="height" type="text" name="height"/>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 22%; float: left;font-weight:300">
                <select id="dimension-unit" class="styled" ">
                    <option name="cm" >cm</option>
                    <option name="inch" >inch</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: `$(your-form-selector).on('submit', function () { change your stuff here });`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you can do something like this:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
//put your code here..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by:

```
$('#selector').on('submit', function () {
    // Your code here
});
```

Or

Use `input[type'submit']` as the selector and use the `click` function on it.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    var width, height;

    if ($('#dimension-unit').val() === "in") {
        width = $('#width').val() * 2.54;
        height = $('#height').val() * 2.54;
    } else {
        width = $('#width').val();
        height = $('#height').val();
    }

    alert("Width: " + width);
    alert("Height: " + height);
});
```

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arfrcch2/)

Answer (score -1):

Create a hidden field, which always has the height in cm. Using jQuery, you can then use the `onkeyup` event to update the cm field whenever the visible one is changed. OR - just send the units to your backend too, and do the conversion there, if required.

Comment: Seriously? Why all of this when they can calculate the conversion in just one go when the form is submitted?

Comment: I tried all the above jquery method but when I click submit it always sends the original value to the API not the changed value while I want it to send the new value